# Entity Framework Code First Auditing many-to-many and one-to-many issues

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've been trying to create an audit trail attempting many different means of doing so from TrackChanges, override of `SaveChanges()` and simply grabbing the entity and getting the original values using `DbEntityEntry.OriginalValues` all of these methods have ultimately boiled down to the same problem. When I have referenced another model as an `ICollection` it does not record this model in the entity.
As a very basic explanation of this issue see the code below:

```
public void Update(Project project)
{
    _ctx.OriginalValues(project);
    _ctx.Projects.Attach(project);
    _ctx.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _ctx.SaveChanges(project);
}
```

The `.OriginalValues` above passes the entity to this method before the save changes has been evoked and I am able to read the values in the entity prior to the user changes. The `OriginalValues` method looks like so:

```
public void OriginalValues(object entity)
{
    var entry = this.Entry(entity);               
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] names = entity.GetType().GetProperties();            

    foreach (var property in names)
    {               
        var n = entry.OriginalValues[property.Name];                   
    }
}
```

The method above I understand is not very elegant or the best practice but it is the latest attempt in a long stream of attempts to read the original values from my entity.

When this code runs the `property.Name` will get to a name called 'Teams' which is referenced as such in the Project model:

```
public class Project
{       
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int MarketId { get; set; } // FK
    [ForeignKey("MarketId")]
    public Market Market { get; set; } // FK Nav   
    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; } // Many to Many Nav 
}
```

An error is thrown which tells me it has not been mapped to Project even though I have used fluent API and data annotations both to try and get a mapping for this.

This is one example I have the same situation occurring in other models but with many to many relationships.

I am a graduate developer and as such don't have a large amount of exposure to .net I hope someone can offer any advice or support on this if possible!

Thanks

Edit: Error message displayed:

> The 'Teams' property does not exist or is not mapped for the type 'Project'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The 'Teams' property does not exist or is not mapped for the type 'Project'.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 78:             foreach (var property in names)
Line 79:             {               
Line 80:                 var n = entry.OriginalValues[property.Name];                   
Line 81:                 
Line 82:             }
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error arises because EF saves the values of each entry in its own object, so the values for navigation properties will be saved in their entries, therefore they are not in the `OriginalValues` of the current object. You can access the navigation properties, like this:

```
foreach (var property in names)
{
    var m = entry.Member(property.Name);
    if (m is DbPropertyEntry)//simple property
    {
         var p = entry.Property(property.Name);
    }
    if (m is DbReferenceEntry)//navigation to single object
    {
         var r = entry.Reference(property.Name);
    }
    if (m is DbCollectionEntry)//navigation to collection
    {
         var c = entry.Collection(property.Name);
    }
}
```

Then you can treat each navigation object as new object and retrieve the original values of them.

**Suggestion:**
EF internally has a tracking system that tracks all changes made to the objects graph, you can query this tracking system and log the changes, something like this. There is no need to track references, because if there is a change in them , then EF detects it.

```
public void OriginalValues(object entity)
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var changed = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x=>x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
    foreach (var entry in changed)
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                Debug.WriteLine("object of type " + entry.Entity.GetType().Name 
                   + "created:");
                foreach(var name in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(name + " : " + entry.CurrentValues[name]);
                }
            break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                Debug.WriteLine("object of type " + entry.Entity.GetType().Name 
                   + "deleted:");
                foreach(var name in entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(name + " : " + entry.OriginalValues[name]);
                }
            break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                Debug.WriteLine("object of type " + entry.Entity.GetType().Name 
                   + "updated:");
                Debug.WriteLine("current values:");
                foreach(var name in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(name + " : " + entry.CurrentValues[name]);
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("original values:");
                foreach(var name in entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(name + " : " + entry.OriginalValues[name]);
                }
            break;
         }
     }
 }
```

**Note:** Make sure to set the state to `Deleted` when you delete an object.

Comment: Hi this is great! But it doesn't show me the original values its displaying the current values. So when I'm break pointing var c the original values should show me 4 teams but instead its showing me the current teams on the project which I've changed to 2.
Have you any ideas on this? I might be missing something?

Comment: If you want to find removed entities you must query the changeTracker for deleted objects

Comment: As far as I know, tracking collection navigations is not a trivial task,

Comment: Ok I'm not too sure how to go about this I'm sorry for my lack of understanding in this area of entity is new to me.

Comment: You can find deleted entries using `ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted)`.

Comment: Yes I tried this but its giving me an error for the Where 
Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: No problem, I added some code for change tracking, I hope it can help you.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to get, the code you've added gives me the teams I have removed from the project which is perfect unfortunately it doesn't get the original values?

Comment: You want the original values of deleted entity?

Comment: I changed it to log the delete entities, it works if the deleted objects loaded to EF though

Comment: Of the modified entity, the teams don't get deleted they come back as modified as the projectId associated with the team has been removed as they have been removed from that project

Comment: Oops, I logged the `CurrentValues` in both loops, I changed it.

Comment: Ah its logging my teams current and original values but not the original values of the project

Comment: What is the state of the project?

Comment: put  `_ctx.OriginalValues(project);` just before the `_ctx.SaveChanges(project);`.